# comma separated javascript function into php

Tags: javascript, php

I want to convert  this `javascript`  function  into `php`

but some lines and rules (Like this for (var h = 0;;) or commas separated lines are not used in php so I'm confused how to write this code in PHP.

This function return time and date

```
function dob(t, e, a) {


            for (var h = 0;;) {
                alert(h)
                if (h += 1, h >= 30) return l; 
                Math.abs(azimuth1 - azimuth2) > 180 * Gt && (azimuth1 < azimuth2 ? azimuth2 -= Qt : azimuth1 -= Qt);
                var u = 1e3; 
                if (l.setSeconds(t.getSeconds() - c), Math.abs(c) < 1) return l;

            }
        }
```

Comment: where is your php code?

Comment: i want to convert above javascript code into php

Comment: and i want to see what you have tried so far to achieve it

Comment: how i convert this line into php  if (l.setSeconds(t.getSeconds() - c), Math.abs(c) < 1) return l;

Comment: You could start by showing us what `l` is supposed to be ... your code does not define that variable or even assign a value to it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do this in PHP:

```
for ($i = 0; ;) {
// logic stuff
}
```

But, it is the same like:

```
$i = 0;
while(true) {
// login stuff
}
```

Comment: this is not an answer for the question

Comment: if (l.setSeconds(t.getSeconds() - c), Math.abs(c) < 1) return l; how to write this linse

Comment: if (h += 1, h >= 30) return l;

Comment: Math.abs(azimuth1 - azimuth2) > 180 * Gt && (azimuth1 < azimuth2 ? azimuth2 -= Qt : azimuth1 -= Qt);

Comment: and how to write above lines in php

Comment: messerbill: Yeah I didn't write the whole algorithm. But the question was about a part of the whole function. It was about the for statement.


@Imran: 
abs($azimuth1 - $azimuth2)  > 180 * $gt && ($azimuth1 < $azimuth2 ? $azimuth2 -= $qt : $azimuth1 -=  $qt)

It's just a guess. I'm not at home, I wrote this on phone.